# How to get a button state change within a for loop?

Tags: arduino-uno, button

I have a `for` loop inside my `void loop()` that triggers a piezo.

What I want to happen is when I press a button, it breaks the loop of the piezo, but right now, it's as if it isn't detecting the button press inside my `for` loop.

Here's my code:

```c
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

#define PIN 6
#define TONE 8
const int buttonPin = 2;

long fadeTime = 5 * 1000L; // X minutes
int colorStops = 256;
int delaySpeed = fadeTime / colorStops;
int notes[] = {262,294,330,349};
int switchState = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(5, PIN, NEO_RGB);

void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT); // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input

  strip.begin();
  strip.show();
}

void loop() {
  // read the state of the pushbutton value:
  switchState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  // Fade in light
  for(int i = 1; i<colorStops; i++){
    for(int np = 0;np<strip.numPixels(); np++){
      strip.setPixelColor(np, strip.Color(i,i,0));
    }
    strip.show();
    delay(delaySpeed);
  }

  // Play tone after light fully bright
  for(int i = 1; i<100; i++){
    // Turn off tone on button press
    if (switchState == HIGH) {
      noTone(TONE);
      break;
    }
    tone(TONE, notes[random(0,3)]);
    delay(100);
  }
}
```

Does `switchState = digitalRead(buttonPin);` only get called at the start of the `void loop` and so it can't detect the button change until then? Something else?

Also, in case it's useful, here's my hardware set up...

[image]

Comment: That'll be because you're not reading the button inside the for loop?

Comment: @Majenko Does `switchState` not just call `digitalRead(buttonPin)`?

Comment: No. `switchState` is assigned the results of performing `digitalRead(buttonPin)` at the time it is called - i.e., at the top of `loop()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't reading the state of the button within your loop.

You only read it the once at the top of your `loop()`:

```
void loop() {
  // read the state of the pushbutton value:
  switchState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
```

You need to replicate that every time you want a new reading from the button - so in your loop you need to add that `digitalRead` line:

```
// Play tone after light fully bright
for(int i = 1; i<100; i++){
  // Turn off tone on button press
  switchState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if (switchState == HIGH) {
    noTone(TONE);
    break;
  }
  tone(TONE, notes[random(0,3)]);
  delay(100);
}
```

Or you can do away with the variable altogether and just test the return value of the `digitalRead`:

```
// Play tone after light fully bright
for(int i = 1; i<100; i++){
  // Turn off tone on button press
  if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH) {
    noTone(TONE);
    break;
  }
  tone(TONE, notes[random(0,3)]);
  delay(100);
}
```